# Multiple tunnel request for serveo.net not working

Tags: jenkins

I have two things running on localhost

A]Jenkins server on localhost:8080

B]Another App on localhost:3000

I wanted to expose both localhost URL so that these applications can be accessed remotely by anyone.

I found option serveo.net I tried firing command:
ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 -R 80:localhost:4200 serveo.net

Result:

I get a response

Forwarding HTTP traffic from https://subdomain1.serveo.net

Forwarding HTTP traffic from https://subdomain2.serveo.net

My Jenkins server is running properly on URL https://subdomain1.serveo.net
But I am having a problem for URL https://subdomain2.serveo.net

How to solve this issue?
Is there any change required in below command for serveo.net?
ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 -R 80:localhost:3000 serveo.net.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run it in 2 separate instances:

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 serveo.net

ssh -R 80:localhost:3000 serveo.net
```

Then you will have access to both URL's from serveo to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Request multiple tunnels at once

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:8888 -R 80:localhost:9999 serveo.net
```

Request a particular subdomain
The subdomain is chosen deterministically based on your IP address, the provided SSH username, and subdomain availability, so you'll often get the same subdomain between restarts. You can also request a particular subdomain:

```
ssh -R incubo:80:localhost:8888 serveo.net
ssh -R incubo.serveo.net:80:localhost:8888 serveo.net
```

In you case use the following command

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 -R 80:localhost:3000 serveo.net
```